# Play framework JDBC ebean mysql exception with characters řů but accepts áõ

Tags: jdbc, playframework, ebean, utf8mb4

Trying to save models and i get a:

**java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: ...**

Saving a text like "jedna dva tři kachna dům a kachní maso"

I'm using default.url="jdbc:mysql://[url]/[database]?characterEncoding=UTF-8"

Comment: Try using `useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`. In my experience those two options tend to appear together.

Comment: Thanks, already tried it, no luck.

Comment: That's only part of the solution; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`řů` have no encoding in latin1; `áõ` do.  That suggests that `CHARACTER SET latin1` is involved somewhere.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

`C599`, etc, are valid utf8 encodings for the corresponding characters.

`?` occurs when the destination character set cannot represent the character.  Again, this points to the column/table being latin1, when it should be `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).

More discussion, and for debugging similar situations:  [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: The problem was that the schema was created with latin1 and the tables were inheriting the encoding. 
Even when i changed the schema encoding, i had to change the tables encoding too or regenerate the database.

Comment: A suitable `ALTER` can possible recover the data, but need more details to be sure not to do the wrong alter.

Comment: Still in dev, losing that was not an issue, but thanks for the tip anyway

Answer (score 0):

Probably has some special character, and the UTF-8 encode that you are forcing may cause some error.

This ASCII string has the following text:

> **String:**
>
> jedna dva tři kachna dům a kachní maso
>
> **ASCII:**
>
> 'jedna dva t\xc5\x99i kachna d\xc5\xafm a kachn\xc3\xad maso'

Comment: If i don't encode it will change to jedna dva t?i kachna d?m a kachn? maso